# jQuery Add Item

Tags: jquery, wordpress, click

So, what I'm trying to do here is `onClick` add another `<li>` that was exactly like the one above it. I have created a for loop in PHP to create the proper fields inside of this `<li>`.

The problem that I am running in to: When you click the `.repatable-add` button I get the "before replace" alert twice and the "after replace" alert does not fire at all. **And ideas?**

```
jQuery('.repeatable-add').click(function() { 
    field = jQuery(this).siblings('ul.image-details').find('li:last').clone(true);  
    fieldLocation = jQuery(this).siblings('ul.image-details').find('li:last');  
    jQuery('input', field).val('').attr('name', function(index, name) {
            alert(name +' before replace');
            return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch, n) {  
            return Number(n) + 1;  
            alert(name +' after replace');
        });  
    })  
    field.insertAfter(fieldLocation, jQuery(this).siblings('ul.image-details').find('li:last'))  
    return false;  
});
```

Comment: dont u need a semicolon before field.insertAfter aswell?

Comment: yeah, but it has no effect on result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're doing with that input part but I think it's because you're trying to do things after a return. Here's what I had:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.repeatable-add').click(function(){
            var copyThis = jQuery(".image-details").find("li:last").clone(true);
            jQuery(".image-details").append(copyThis);
            var name = jQuery("input").attr("name");
            var count = name.replace(/\d+/, '');
            var newCount = count++;
            jQuery("input").attr("name",name.replace(newCount.toString(),count.toString()));
        return false;  
    });  
});
</script>

<ul class="image-details">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<input name="ithas1" />
<button class='repeatable-add'>button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, Pix. I'm not sure why my question got duplicated, but this worked out great, with the exceptions to my edit(s). Should come in handy for other people too!

Answer (score 1):

There's a return before the alert, so the alert will never be executed:

```
{  
            return Number(n) + 1;  
            alert(name +' after replace');
        });
```

Comment: Ok, cool. That still doesn't explain why the "before replace" fires twice.. And the second time the "before replace" is fired the value of name returns undefined.

Comment: The idea here was to have a return and a callback on that return, with another return. I get why I wasn't getting the second alert, but I am still baffled as to why the rest of it isn't working as expected.. I reformatted my code as @PixMatch explained, but I'm still hoping I can find a better answer to why THIS method isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the alert for "after replace" is simply not firing since there is a return statement directly before it.

Comment: Ok, true. But the biggest mystery to me is why the "before replace" is firing twice. And the second time it fires the value of name is undefined.